# boto3 instances.filter array

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to print out list of EC2 instances that failed from status check

When I do a instance filter like this

```
instances = conn.instances.filter(
    Filters=[
        {'Name': 'instance-id', 'Values': ['i-017357c1c4a1a96f8', 'i-07e399b452c7100c3']}
        ]
)


for instance in instances:
    instance_name = get_tag(instance.tags)        
    print (instance_name, instance.id, instance.instance_type)
```

I was able to print out the instances.

But when I do the filter in an array, it does not work even though the failed_instances() array consists of: `['i-017357c1c4a1a96f8', 'i-07e399b452c7100c3']`

```
instances = conn.instances.filter(
    Filters=[
        {'Name': 'instance-id', 'Values': [failed_instances]}
        ]
)

print(failed_instances)

['i-017357c1c4a1a96f8', 'i-07e399b452c7100c3']
```

Any idea?

---

OK made some modifications, but I cant fill it up in the array. any idea? maybe the instanceID is wrong?

```
instances = conn.instances.filter(
    InstanceIds = failed_instances
)

#print(failed_instances)
tag_names = []
for instance in instances:
    instance_name = get_tag(instance.tags) 
 #   print (instance_name, instance.id, instance.instance_type)
    tag_names.append(i["instance_name"])
print(tag_names)
```

Comment: Code is specific.  You should be specific in your questions about it.  "failed_instances() array" what does that mean?  Is `failed_instances` a function returning an array?  `()` denotes function call.  You say "does not work" - no error to include in question?

Comment: failed_instances is an array I got from another loop

Comment: print(failed_instances) shows ['i-017357c1c4a1a96f8', 'i-07e399b452c7100c3']

Comment: ok got it working now with tag_names.append(instance_name)

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your code, but it sounds like `failed_instances` is already an array.  Then you put it into *another* array when you say `[failed_instances]`.

Instead, you should write:

```
instances = conn.instances.filter(
    Filters=[
        {'Name': 'instance-id', 'Values': failed_instances}
        ]
)
```